# Pause Macro to enter data into a field

Tags: excel, vba, user-input, pause

I have some code to format and edit a spreadsheet all i want is to have the macro pause and ask the individual to enter a reference number into cell A2.

I have tried all sorts of solutions from the www but it seems they are all extremely complicated and way above my level.

```
Range("A2").Select
```

Enter reference number

etctetc

Just to have a reference number in a cell and for the rest of the macro to carry on as normal.

Comment: Can you not have an InputBox instead of asking user to enter value in a Cell ?

Comment: Here is a link on how to make an input box and then put that value in a cell. https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/inputbox-function.html

Answer (score 0):

The `InputBox()` is probably the best way to stop a VBA code, when waiting for user input. This is a simple demo. concatenating some numbers with the input from the box:

[image]

And after entering "tralala":

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim ii As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        For ii = 1 To 10
        Worksheets(1).Cells(ii, i) = i + ii
        Next
    Next

    Worksheets(1).Range("A2") = InputBox("Please enter some value in range A2")

    For i = 1 To 10
        For ii = 1 To 10
        Worksheets(1).Cells(ii, i) = i + ii & Worksheets(1).Range("A2")
        Next
    Next


End Sub
```

- [VBA InputBox() function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function)